# Windows Server 2012 Standard entitlement in Microsoft Action Pack Subscription

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012

In the Microsoft Action Pack Subscription Windows Server 2012 Std shows "2" as the entitlement.

I'm not sure what this means. A "normal" Server 2012 Std includes:
1. One activation for the host (Hyper-V)
2. Two activations for guests on the same host
....making a total of three activations

I'm pretty sure from reading some threads that partners don't get the same as a normal Std license, but it's pretty fuzzy.

Does anyone know what the story really is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can perform only two activations:

1. On bare metal
2. As a VM